How to adapt this Module to include the extra Point?
I am using Arc3D to draw arcs that represent angles (θ & ɸ) in a 3D technical drawing.

Each is further delineated by the translucent triangles bounding the angle. I'd prefer to confine the translucency to a region bound by the arc and the corner inside the arc. This corner point is the m attribute in the following code.
{a, b, m} = {{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}};

Arc3D[{a_, b_, m_}, n_ : 60, prim_ : Line] := 
 Module[{\[Alpha], lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha}, 
  lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
  axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
  aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
  tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
  prim@Table[m + tm . (a - m), {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}]]

Arc3DPolygon[{a_, b_, m_}, n_ : 60, prim_ : Polygon] :=
 Module[
  {\[Alpha], lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha},
  lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
  axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
  aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
  tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
  prim@Table[
    m + tm . (a - m),
    {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}
    ]
  ]

arc = Graphics3D[{
    Arc3D[{a, b, m}, 20]
    }];
arcFilled = Graphics3D[{
    Point[m], Opacity[.4], Arc3DPolygon[{a, b, m}, 20]
    }];
GraphicsGrid[{{arc, arcFilled}}]

As seen, Arc3DPolygon hacks the original Arc3D module to replace the Line with a Polygon, producing this effect.

How should the Arc3DPolygon module be changed to allow the addition of the m point (on the upper right in the 2nd graphic), to form the region required? Or, more generally, how should this problem be approached?

Tha basic idea would be Append[Table[..], point], though you may have to use Insert[] if Table[] does something really weird.

Thanks @MichaelE2, that worked a treat! The implementation is below: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/306698/100987

This comment contained the solution. Namely to Append[Table[..], point]
Here is the implementation of Arc3DFilled:
{a, b, m} = {{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}};

Arc3D[{a_, b_, m_}, n_ : 60, prim_ : Line] := 
 Module[{\[Alpha], lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha}, 
  lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
  axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
  aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
  tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
  prim@Table[m + tm . (a - m), {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}]]

Arc3DFilled[{a_, b_, m_}, n_ : 60, prim_ : Polygon] :=
 Module[
  {\[Alpha], lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha},
  lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
  axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
  aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
  tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
  prim@Append[Table[
     m + tm . (a - m),
     {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}
     ], m]
  ]

arc = Graphics3D[{
    Point[m],
    Arc3D[{a, b, m}, 20]
    }];
arcFilled = Graphics3D[{
    Opacity[.4],
    Arc3DFilled[{a, b, m}, 20]
    }];
GraphicsGrid[{{arc, arcFilled}}]

The result:

